# Get date and time picker value from a single dialog fragment and set it in EditText

Tags: android, datepicker, datetimepicker, timepicker

I am working on an application in which the user can set the date and time. I want to set the date and time in a single dialog fragment and set it to edit text. Is it possible to use a date and time picker in 1 dialog fragment? If it is, how do you do it?
Currently I am getting the time from the dialog fragment and then setting it to the `EditText`.

My code is

```
LaterTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.PickUp_later_TextView);



       LaterTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);

                }
        });




}


protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:

        // set time picker as current time
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute,
                false);

    }
    return null;
}

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
            int selectedMinute) {
        hour = selectedHour;
        minute = selectedMinute;

        // set current time into TextView
        setDate_time_EditTExt.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour))
                .append(":").append(pad(minute)));



    }
};
private static String pad(int c) {
    if (c >= 10)
        return String.valueOf(c);
    else
        return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
}
```

I want to set the date and time from the same dialog fragment.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Date Picker** and **Time Picker** both *in single dialog*. check this code.

**main_Activity.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    custom = new CustomDateTimePicker(this,
            new CustomDateTimePicker.ICustomDateTimeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSet(Dialog dialog, Calendar calendarSelected,
                        Date dateSelected, int year, String monthFullName,
                        String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int date,
                        String weekDayFullName, String weekDayShortName,
                        int hour24, int hour12, int min, int sec,
                        String AM_PM) {
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.lablel))
                            .setText(calendarSelected
                                            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                                    + "/" + (monthNumber+1) + "/" + year
                                    + ", " + hour12 + ":" + min
                                    + " " + AM_PM);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }
            });
    /**
     * Pass Directly current time format it will return AM and PM if you set
     * false
     */
    custom.set24HourFormat(false);
    /**
     * Pass Directly current data and time to show when it pop up
     */
    custom.setDate(Calendar.getInstance());

    findViewById(R.id.button_date).setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    custom.showDialog();
                }
            });
}

CustomDateTimePicker custom;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

**CustomDateTimePicker.java**

```
public class CustomDateTimePicker implements OnClickListener {
private DatePicker datePicker;
private TimePicker timePicker;
private ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;

private final int SET_DATE = 100, SET_TIME = 101, SET = 102, CANCEL = 103;

private Button btn_setDate, btn_setTime, btn_set, btn_cancel;

private Calendar calendar_date = null;

private Activity activity;

private ICustomDateTimeListener iCustomDateTimeListener = null;

private Dialog dialog;

private boolean is24HourView = true, isAutoDismiss = true;

private int selectedHour, selectedMinute;

public CustomDateTimePicker(Activity a,
        ICustomDateTimeListener customDateTimeListener) {
    activity = a;
    iCustomDateTimeListener = customDateTimeListener;

    dialog = new Dialog(activity);
    dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            resetData();
        }
    });

    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    View dialogView = getDateTimePickerLayout();
    dialog.setContentView(dialogView);
}

public View getDateTimePickerLayout() {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linear_match_wrap = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linear_wrap_wrap = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frame_match_wrap = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams button_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);

    LinearLayout linear_main = new LinearLayout(activity);
    linear_main.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);
    linear_main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linear_main.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    LinearLayout linear_child = new LinearLayout(activity);
    linear_child.setLayoutParams(linear_wrap_wrap);
    linear_child.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    LinearLayout linear_top = new LinearLayout(activity);
    linear_top.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);

    btn_setDate = new Button(activity);
    btn_setDate.setLayoutParams(button_params);
    btn_setDate.setText("Set Date");
    btn_setDate.setId(SET_DATE);
    btn_setDate.setOnClickListener(this);

    btn_setTime = new Button(activity);
    btn_setTime.setLayoutParams(button_params);
    btn_setTime.setText("Set Time");
    btn_setTime.setId(SET_TIME);
    btn_setTime.setOnClickListener(this);

    linear_top.addView(btn_setDate);
    linear_top.addView(btn_setTime);

    viewSwitcher = new ViewSwitcher(activity);
    viewSwitcher.setLayoutParams(frame_match_wrap);

    datePicker = new DatePicker(activity);
    timePicker = new TimePicker(activity);
    timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new OnTimeChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            selectedHour = hourOfDay;
            selectedMinute = minute;
        }
    });

    viewSwitcher.addView(timePicker);
    viewSwitcher.addView(datePicker);

    LinearLayout linear_bottom = new LinearLayout(activity);
    linear_match_wrap.topMargin = 8;
    linear_bottom.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);

    btn_set = new Button(activity);
    btn_set.setLayoutParams(button_params);
    btn_set.setText("Set");
    btn_set.setId(SET);
    btn_set.setOnClickListener(this);

    btn_cancel = new Button(activity);
    btn_cancel.setLayoutParams(button_params);
    btn_cancel.setText("Cancel");
    btn_cancel.setId(CANCEL);
    btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

    linear_bottom.addView(btn_set);
    linear_bottom.addView(btn_cancel);

    linear_child.addView(linear_top);
    linear_child.addView(viewSwitcher);
    linear_child.addView(linear_bottom);

    linear_main.addView(linear_child);

    return linear_main;
}

public void showDialog() {
    if (!dialog.isShowing()) {
        if (calendar_date == null)
            calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

        selectedHour = calendar_date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        selectedMinute = calendar_date.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        timePicker.setIs24HourView(is24HourView);
        timePicker.setCurrentHour(selectedHour);
        timePicker.setCurrentMinute(selectedMinute);

        datePicker.updateDate(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar_date.get(Calendar.DATE));

        dialog.show();

        btn_setDate.performClick();
    }
}

public void setAutoDismiss(boolean isAutoDismiss) {
    this.isAutoDismiss = isAutoDismiss;
}

public void dismissDialog() {
    if (!dialog.isShowing())
        dialog.dismiss();
}

public void setDate(Calendar calendar) {
    if (calendar != null)
        calendar_date = calendar;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    if (date != null) {
        calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar_date.setTime(date);
    }
}

public void setDate(int year, int month, int day) {
    if (month < 12 && month >= 0 && day < 32 && day >= 0 && year > 100
            && year < 3000) {
        calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar_date.set(year, month, day);
    }

}

public void setTimeIn24HourFormat(int hourIn24Format, int minute) {
    if (hourIn24Format < 24 && hourIn24Format >= 0 && minute >= 0
            && minute < 60) {
        if (calendar_date == null)
            calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar_date.set(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), hourIn24Format,
                minute);

        is24HourView = true;
    }
}

public void setTimeIn12HourFormat(int hourIn12Format, int minute,
        boolean isAM) {
    if (hourIn12Format < 13 && hourIn12Format > 0 && minute >= 0
            && minute < 60) {
        if (hourIn12Format == 12)
            hourIn12Format = 0;

        int hourIn24Format = hourIn12Format;

        if (!isAM)
            hourIn24Format += 12;

        if (calendar_date == null)
            calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar_date.set(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), hourIn24Format,
                minute);

        is24HourView = false;
    }
}

public void set24HourFormat(boolean is24HourFormat) {
    is24HourView = is24HourFormat;
}

public interface ICustomDateTimeListener {
    public void onSet(Dialog dialog, Calendar calendarSelected,
            Date dateSelected, int year, String monthFullName,
            String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int date,
            String weekDayFullName, String weekDayShortName, int hour24,
            int hour12, int min, int sec, String AM_PM);

    public void onCancel();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case SET_DATE:
        btn_setTime.setEnabled(true);
        btn_setDate.setEnabled(false);
        viewSwitcher.showNext();
        break;

    case SET_TIME:
        btn_setTime.setEnabled(false);
        btn_setDate.setEnabled(true);
        viewSwitcher.showPrevious();
        break;

    case SET:
        if (iCustomDateTimeListener != null) {
            int month = datePicker.getMonth();
            int year = datePicker.getYear();
            int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();


            calendar_date.set(year, month, day, selectedHour,
                    selectedMinute);

            iCustomDateTimeListener.onSet(dialog, calendar_date,
                    calendar_date.getTime(), calendar_date
                            .get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    getMonthFullName(calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH)),
                    getMonthShortName(calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH)),
                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar_date
                            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                    getWeekDayFullName(calendar_date
                            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)),
                    getWeekDayShortName(calendar_date
                            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)), calendar_date
                            .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                    getHourIn12Format(calendar_date
                            .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)), calendar_date
                            .get(Calendar.MINUTE), calendar_date
                            .get(Calendar.SECOND), getAMPM(calendar_date));
        }
        if (dialog.isShowing() && isAutoDismiss)
            dialog.dismiss();
        break;

    case CANCEL:
        if (iCustomDateTimeListener != null)
            iCustomDateTimeListener.onCancel();
        if (dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
        break;
    }
}

/**
 * @param date
 *            date in String
 * @param fromFormat
 *            format of your <b>date</b> eg: if your date is 2011-07-07
 *            09:09:09 then your format will be <b>yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss</b>
 * @param toFormat
 *            format to which you want to convert your <b>date</b> eg: if
 *            required format is 31 July 2011 then the toFormat should be
 *            <b>d MMMM yyyy</b>
 * @return formatted date
 */
public static String convertDate(String date, String fromFormat,
        String toFormat) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(fromFormat);
        Date d = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(d);

        simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(toFormat);
        simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
        date = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return date;
}

private String getMonthFullName(int monthNumber) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber);

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
    simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
    String monthName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

    return monthName;
}

private String getMonthShortName(int monthNumber) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber);

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
    simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
    String monthName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

    return monthName;
}

private String getWeekDayFullName(int weekDayNumber) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, weekDayNumber);

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
    String weekName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

    return weekName;
}

private String getWeekDayShortName(int weekDayNumber) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, weekDayNumber);

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE");
    simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
    String weekName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

    return weekName;
}

private int getHourIn12Format(int hour24) {
    int hourIn12Format = 0;

    if (hour24 == 0)
        hourIn12Format = 12;
    else if (hour24 <= 12)
        hourIn12Format = hour24;
    else
        hourIn12Format = hour24 - 12;

    return hourIn12Format;
}

private String getAMPM(Calendar calendar) {
    String ampm = (calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == (Calendar.AM)) ? "AM"
            : "PM";
    return ampm;
}

private void resetData() {
    calendar_date = null;
    is24HourView = true;
}

public static String pad(int integerToPad) {
    if (integerToPad >= 10 || integerToPad < 0)
        return String.valueOf(integerToPad);
    else
        return "0" + String.valueOf(integerToPad);
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lablel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/lablel"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:text="Date Time Picker" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I got your point @sandip, in this code action listener on the button which shows the calender pop up box... But my problem is that I want  action listener which shows both the date and picker time in 1 dialog fragment. Means  1 date picker and 1 time picker in same dialog fragment and these pickers value in one textfield... Are u getting me?? .... Thanks for help and thanks in advance for more help.....

Comment: @user1822884, it means you create custom dialog which contains both date and time picker. if yes then i give you code for that.

Comment: and use these `imports import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener;
import android.view.Gravity;
`

Comment: and `import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;  
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;`  **both comments for CustomDateTimePicker.java**

Comment: It works fine with Activity Class, When I use this in non-activity class with context it throws NullPointerException while clicking set button. The Exception occurs at onSet method. Any Idea to rectify this issue?

Comment: How can i restrict past dates in this?

Comment: I think the question was how can you have date and time picker in single dialog. No doubt this will work but not very user friendly as they have to switch between setting date and time. Ideally both the date and time picker would be presented in a single dialog (without buttons to hide/show date/time pickers)

Answer (score 4):

This is very simple:

You have to set the Date/Time of the Dialog in the Bundle object and set that Bundle in `Message` object with the Message's `setData` method then in the activity where you want to retrieve those Date/Time values you have to make

Here is How i am doing this:

```
public class DatePickerDialog extends DialogFragment {
    private Handler dialogPickerHandler;
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;   
    private Bundle mBundle;

    /** This is the one argument constructor */
    public DatePickerDialog(Handler h) {
        /**
         * Getting the reference to the message handler instance instantiated in
         * calling activity
         */

        dialogPickerHandler = h;
    } // end constructor

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mBundle = getArguments();

        mYear = mBundle.getInt("set_year");
        mDay = mBundle.getInt("set_day");
        mMonth = mBundle.getInt("set_month");

        return new android.app.DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    }

    private OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {

            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;

            Bundle b = new Bundle();

            b.putInt("set_year", mYear);
            b.putInt("set_month", mMonth);
            b.putInt("set_day", mDay);

            Message m = new Message();

            m.setData(b);

            dialogPickerHandler.sendMessage(m);

        }
    };

}
```

And in the Activity in which you want to retrieve those values you have to do the following:

```
 private Bundle mBundle;
    private int mtYear;
    private int mDay;
    private int mMonth;
    private Calendar your_date_object;
    private EditText your_edit_text;
    private SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat

    Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message m) {
            mBundle = m.getData();

            mtYear = mBundle.getInt("set_year");
            mDay = mBundle.getInt("set_day");
            mMonth = mBundle.getInt("set_month");


            /** update the time on the start Date Button */
            your_date_object.set(mtYear, mMonth, mDay);

            your_edit_text.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(startDate
                        .getTime()));


        }
    };
```

Make sure your initialize the `simpleDateFormat`, `your_date_object` in the `onCreate` method of your activity as follows:

```
/** Initialize the simpleDateFormat object */
    simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy dd, MM");

    /** Initialize the your_date_object */

    your_date_object = new GregorianCalendar();
```

Thats it. :)

Comment: I trid this.... but its stop working... I want to show date and time picker in same dialog fragment and user can set date and set this in the edit text and text view..... My code is working for time.... I want that date picker should appear in same dialog fragment... and set in same edit text.  can u help me plz..... Thanks in advance

Comment: I am getting month=0 coul you pls fix it

Comment: Getting nullPointer at DialogPickerHandler.setMessage(m); any possible reason?

Answer (score 0):

First of Thanks @Mr. Sandy
Edited @Mr. Sandy Code with due respect,to add some more additional functionality.

- No Date from Past
- Error Msg
- Time In Milliseconds

**Main_Activity.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    custom = new CustomDateTimePicker(this,
            new CustomDateTimePicker.ICustomDateTimeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSet(Dialog dialog, Calendar calendarSelected,
                        Date dateSelected, int year, String monthFullName,
                        String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int date,
                        String weekDayFullName, String weekDayShortName,
                        int hour24, int hour12, int min, int sec,
                        String AM_PM, long _timeInMillies) {
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.lablel))
                            .setText(calendarSelected
                                            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                                    + "/" + (monthNumber+1) + "/" + year
                                    + ", " + hour12 + ":" + min
                                    + " " + AM_PM);
long timeInMillies = _timeInMillies;

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }
            });
    /**
     * Pass Directly current time format it will return AM and PM if you set
     * false
     */
    custom.set24HourFormat(false);
    /**
     * Pass Directly current data and time to show when it pop up
     */
    custom.setDate(Calendar.getInstance());

    findViewById(R.id.button_date).setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    custom.showDialog();
                }
            });
}

CustomDateTimePicker custom;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

**CustomDateTimePicker.java**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;


public class CustomDateTimePicker implements OnClickListener {
    private DatePicker datePicker;
    private TimePicker timePicker;
    private ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;

    private final int SET_DATE = 100, SET_TIME = 101, SET = 102, CANCEL = 103;

    private Button btn_setDate, btn_setTime, btn_set, btn_cancel;

    private TextView errMsg;

    private Calendar calendar_date = null;

    private Activity activity;

    private ICustomDateTimeListener iCustomDateTimeListener = null;

    private Dialog dialog;

    private boolean is24HourView = true, isAutoDismiss = true;

    private int selectedHour, selectedMinute;

    public CustomDateTimePicker(Activity a,
            ICustomDateTimeListener customDateTimeListener) {
        activity = a;
        iCustomDateTimeListener = customDateTimeListener;

        dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                resetData();

            }
        });
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        View dialogView = getDateTimePickerLayout();
        dialog.setContentView(dialogView);
    }

    public View getDateTimePickerLayout() {


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams linear_match_wrap = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams linear_wrap_wrap = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams frame_match_wrap = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams button_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);

        LinearLayout linear_main = new LinearLayout(activity);
        linear_main.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);
        linear_main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linear_main.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        LinearLayout linear_child = new LinearLayout(activity);
        linear_child.setLayoutParams(linear_wrap_wrap);
        linear_child.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LinearLayout linear_top = new LinearLayout(activity);
        linear_top.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);

        btn_setDate = new Button(activity);
        btn_setDate.setLayoutParams(button_params);
        btn_setDate.setText("Set Date");
        btn_setDate.setId(SET_DATE);
        btn_setDate.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn_setTime = new Button(activity);
        btn_setTime.setLayoutParams(button_params);
        btn_setTime.setText("Set Time");
        btn_setTime.setId(SET_TIME);
        btn_setTime.setOnClickListener(this);

        linear_top.addView(btn_setDate);
        linear_top.addView(btn_setTime);

        viewSwitcher = new ViewSwitcher(activity);
        viewSwitcher.setLayoutParams(frame_match_wrap);

        datePicker = new DatePicker(activity);
        timePicker = new TimePicker(activity);
        timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new OnTimeChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                selectedHour = hourOfDay;
                selectedMinute = minute;
            }
        });

        viewSwitcher.addView(timePicker);
        viewSwitcher.addView(datePicker);

        LinearLayout linear_bottom = new LinearLayout(activity);
        linear_match_wrap.topMargin = 8;
        linear_bottom.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);

        btn_set = new Button(activity);
        btn_set.setLayoutParams(button_params);
        btn_set.setText("Set");
        btn_set.setId(SET);
        btn_set.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn_cancel = new Button(activity);
        btn_cancel.setLayoutParams(button_params);
        btn_cancel.setText("Cancel");
        btn_cancel.setId(CANCEL);
        btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

        linear_bottom.addView(btn_set);
        linear_bottom.addView(btn_cancel);

        errMsg = new TextView(activity);
        errMsg.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);
        errMsg.setText("Can't Select Date From Past.");
        errMsg.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.Red));
        errMsg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        errMsg.setTypeface(face);
        errMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        linear_child.addView(linear_top);
        linear_child.addView(viewSwitcher);
        linear_child.addView(errMsg);
        linear_child.addView(linear_bottom);

        linear_main.addView(linear_child);

        return linear_main;
    }

    public void showDialog() {
        if (!dialog.isShowing()) {
            if (calendar_date == null)
                calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

            selectedHour = calendar_date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            selectedMinute = calendar_date.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            timePicker.setIs24HourView(is24HourView);
            timePicker.setCurrentHour(selectedHour);
            timePicker.setCurrentMinute(selectedMinute);

            datePicker.updateDate(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.DATE));

            dialog.show();

            btn_setDate.performClick();
        }
    }

    public void setAutoDismiss(boolean isAutoDismiss) {
        this.isAutoDismiss = isAutoDismiss;
    }

    public void dismissDialog() {
        if (!dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
    }

    public void setDate(Calendar calendar) {
        if (calendar != null)
            calendar_date = calendar;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        if (date != null) {
            calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar_date.setTime(date);
        }
    }

    public void setDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        if (month < 12 && month >= 0 && day < 32 && day >= 0 && year > 100
                && year < 3000) {
            calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar_date.set(year, month, day);
        }

    }

    public void setTimeIn24HourFormat(int hourIn24Format, int minute) {
        if (hourIn24Format < 24 && hourIn24Format >= 0 && minute >= 0
                && minute < 60) {
            if (calendar_date == null)
                calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar_date.set(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), hourIn24Format,
                    minute);

            is24HourView = true;
        }
    }

    public void setTimeIn12HourFormat(int hourIn12Format, int minute,
            boolean isAM) {
        if (hourIn12Format < 13 && hourIn12Format > 0 && minute >= 0
                && minute < 60) {
            if (hourIn12Format == 12)
                hourIn12Format = 0;

            int hourIn24Format = hourIn12Format;

            if (!isAM)
                hourIn24Format += 12;

            if (calendar_date == null)
                calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar_date.set(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), hourIn24Format,
                    minute);

            is24HourView = false;
        }
    }

    public void set24HourFormat(boolean is24HourFormat) {
        is24HourView = is24HourFormat;
    }

    public interface ICustomDateTimeListener {
        public void onSet(Dialog dialog, Calendar calendarSelected,
                Date dateSelected, int year, String monthFullName,
                String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int date,
                String weekDayFullName, String weekDayShortName, int hour24,
                int hour12, int min, int sec, String AM_PM, long timeinMilliSec);

        public void onCancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case SET_DATE:
            btn_setTime.setEnabled(true);
            btn_setDate.setEnabled(false);
            viewSwitcher.showNext();
            break;

        case SET_TIME:
            btn_setTime.setEnabled(false);
            btn_setDate.setEnabled(true);
            viewSwitcher.showPrevious();
            break;

        case SET:
            if (iCustomDateTimeListener != null) {
                int month = datePicker.getMonth();
                int year = datePicker.getYear();
                int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                Log.i("Date",
                        " " + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " "
                                + datePicker.getYear() + " Month"
                                + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + " "
                                + datePicker.getMonth() + "Date "
                                + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " "
                                + datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
                if (cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) <= datePicker.getYear()
                        && cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) <= datePicker.getMonth()
                        && cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) <= datePicker
                                .getDayOfMonth()) {
                    calendar_date.set(year, month, day, selectedHour,
                            selectedMinute);

                    iCustomDateTimeListener
                            .onSet(dialog, calendar_date, calendar_date
                                    .getTime(), calendar_date
                                    .get(Calendar.YEAR),
                                    getMonthFullName(calendar_date
                                            .get(Calendar.MONTH)),
                                    getMonthShortName(calendar_date
                                            .get(Calendar.MONTH)),
                                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                                    getWeekDayFullName(calendar_date
                                            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)),
                                    getWeekDayShortName(calendar_date
                                            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)),
                                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                                    getHourIn12Format(calendar_date
                                            .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)),
                                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                                    calendar_date.get(Calendar.SECOND),
                                    getAMPM(calendar_date),calendar_date.getTimeInMillis());

                    if (dialog.isShowing() && isAutoDismiss)
                        dialog.dismiss();
                } else {
                    errMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
            break;

        case CANCEL:
            if (iCustomDateTimeListener != null)
                iCustomDateTimeListener.onCancel();
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
            break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param date
     *            date in String
     * @param fromFormat
     *            format of your <b>date</b> eg: if your date is 2011-07-07
     *            09:09:09 then your format will be <b>yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss</b>
     * @param toFormat
     *            format to which you want to convert your <b>date</b> eg: if
     *            required format is 31 July 2011 then the toFormat should be
     *            <b>d MMMM yyyy</b>
     * @return formatted date
     */
    public static String convertDate(String date, String fromFormat,
            String toFormat) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(fromFormat);
            Date d = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(d);

            simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(toFormat);
            simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
            date = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return date;
    }

    private String getMonthFullName(int monthNumber) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber);

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
        simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
        String monthName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

        return monthName;
    }

    private String getMonthShortName(int monthNumber) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber);

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
        simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
        String monthName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

        return monthName;
    }

    private String getWeekDayFullName(int weekDayNumber) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, weekDayNumber);

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
        simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
        String weekName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

        return weekName;
    }

    private String getWeekDayShortName(int weekDayNumber) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, weekDayNumber);

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE");
        simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
        String weekName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

        return weekName;
    }

    private int getHourIn12Format(int hour24) {
        int hourIn12Format = 0;

        if (hour24 == 0)
            hourIn12Format = 12;
        else if (hour24 <= 12)
            hourIn12Format = hour24;
        else
            hourIn12Format = hour24 - 12;

        return hourIn12Format;
    }

    private String getAMPM(Calendar calendar) {
        String ampm = (calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == (Calendar.AM)) ? "AM"
                : "PM";
        return ampm;
    }

    private void resetData() {
        calendar_date = null;
        is24HourView = true;
    }

    public static String pad(int integerToPad) {
        if (integerToPad >= 10 || integerToPad < 0)
            return String.valueOf(integerToPad);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(integerToPad);
    }
}
```