# Is there a way to tell which button opened a dialoginterface?

Tags: android, button

I am using the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354089/get-date-and-time-picker-value-from-dialog-fragment-and-set-it-in-edit-text) question (the first answer) to pick the date and time in one dialoginterface box. However I am doing a start time and an end time, so there are two buttons that open the same dialoginterface. Is there a way to find out which one opened the dialog interface, so that in my `onSet` method I can do something like:

```
    if (start_button opened the dialog) {  
        return result to start time TextView;  
    } else if (end_button opened the dialog) {  
        return result to end time TextView;  
    }
```

Comment: How about setting a boolean flag to true inside whichever button gets selected, then you can check that flag in your conditionals to figure out which button was selected.  Of course maintain the flag as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `android:id=@+id/buttonX` value to work out what button was pressed.

Something like this (maybe) in your Activity code:

```
private int mButtonPressed = -1;

... heap of code ...

public void pressedButton(View view) {
    mButtonPressed = view.getId();
}

// your code from your question
if (mButtonPressed == R.id.buttonX) {  
    return result to start time TextView;  
} else if (mButtonPressed == R.id.buttonY) {  
    return result to end time TextView;  
}
```

And in your layout XML for the button, make sure you include:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonX"  
    android:onclick="pressedButton"
    ... more attributes ...
/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonY"  
    android:onclick="pressedButton"
    ... more attributes ...
/>
```